# How to solve numerically ODE modeling tumor growth?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to reproduce an experiment on tumor growth using a model with a differential equation. I am following a [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1532046415001513) that models the tumor growth as

$\frac{dx}{dt} = g(x)$

$x(0) = N_0$

They use for $g(x)$ the following function:

$g(x) = ax ln(\frac{b}{x})$ (1) (Gompertzian growth)

where $a$, $b$ and $N_0$ are some known and fixed values. $a$ is the growth rate constant, $b$ id the maximum size of the tumor and $N_0$ is the initial size of the tumor. In this case $N_0=1$.

So, they state that integrating equation $g(x)$ over x and applying boundary condition $x(0) = 1$ you get:

$x(t) = b(\frac{b}{N_0})^{-e^{-at}}$ (2)

that means the "number of cells (size) in tumor on time $t$".

Well, I am using numerical methods to solve Ordinary Differential Equations. For simplicity let us say Euler's Method. If I use Euler's method to solve the equation and compare it to exact solution (which I understand is Equation 1) I do not get close enough solutions.

[image: Picture]
(In BLUE the "exact solution they state", in GREEN solution of Euler's method, GREEN is not completely flat. But not close to the values of the BLUE)

Also, I used a MATLAB to integrate equation 1 and got

$x(t) = a (\frac{ln(\frac{b}{t})t^2}{2} + \frac{t^2}{4})$

And when compare this to my results they make sense. However the values of $y$ are not the one they mention on the paper, of course, they are using the Eq. 1.

[image]

Well. Am I not understanding correctly the differential equation? Is the Eq.2 a correct integration over Eq. 1?

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong? (if something)

What Should I Do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the paper you are following and what does each constant represent?

Comment: @Jam, $a$ is the growth rate constant, $b$ id the maximum dize of the tumor and $N_0$ is the initial size of the tumor. In this case $N_0=1$. The paper is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1532046415001513

Comment: Just to clarify the procedure here. You start with $x$ as a function of $t$, you substitute it into $g(x)$, then use that to solve a differential equation for $y$?

Comment: No wonder it was confusing, I was wondering where your variable $y$ came from.

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX in the paper you linked, there is no variable $y$. The differential equation should read $x' = g(x)$.

Comment: @whpowell96, right. Typo mistake. Fixed it

Comment: Reading you comments I wondered. Should I use Eq 2. As the value of $x$ in Eq. 1 and use Euler's method with that? Or Eq. 2 is just the result of solving the ODE separating variables? (Also, in the plots the axes values should be $t$ instead of $x$ and $x$ instead of $y$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive their analytic expression by first taking the growth rate as a composite function of time, $(g\circ x)(t)$, and using this to derive the tumor cell number function, $x(t)$. I'm using this notation as opposed to $g(x)$ to emphasise that $x$ is also a function of time.

$$\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm{d}x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}&=(g\circ x)(t)
\\
\end{align}$$

Using the assumption that the growth rate is Gompertzian, $(g\circ x)(t)=ax(t)\ln\left(\frac{b}{x(t)}\right)$, with constants, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, we can plug this into the previous equation to get $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}=ax(t)\ln\left(\frac{b}{x(t)}\right)$. Shift all $x(t)$ terms to one side (LHS) and all $t$ terms to the other. Then integrate wrt. $t$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus to deal with the derivative term.

$$
\begin{align}&\frac1{x(t)\ln\left(\frac{b}{x(t)}\right)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}=a
\\
&\int \frac1{x(t)\ln\left(\frac{b}{x(t)}\right)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int a\,\mathrm{d}t
\\
&\int \frac1{x(t)\ln\left(\frac{b}{x(t)}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x(t)=at+C
\end{align}$$

Then, since $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{u\ln(b/u)}\,\mathrm{d}u=-\ln\ln\frac{b}{u}+C$, we have $\displaystyle -\ln\ln\frac{b}{x(t)}=at+C$ and therefore,

$$
x(t)=b\exp\left(-\exp\left(-\left(at+C\right)\right)\right)$$

setting $x(0)=N_0$ and solving for $C=-\ln\ln\left(\frac{b}{N_{0}}\right)$ shows that this agrees with the solution of the paper and intuitively makes sense since we'd expect the curve to be sigmoidal. The paper was slightly disingenuous when it suggested that you integrate wrt. $x$, since there was some preceding algebra that you'd have needed to do, and it's sort of an integration wrt. $t$ in disguise. Your solution of $a\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{2}}{4}\right)$ suggests that you were integrating $g$ outright wrt. $x$ without taking this into account. If you do this, you get an expression for $\displaystyle \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}x
$, which doesn't help much since we essentially want the differentials to cancel. We can also see that it was intuitively wrong, since it exploded to $-\infty$ with large $t$.

---

To approach the problem numerically with Euler's method, we have a system defined by $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=g(x),\ x(0)=N_0$ with the Gompertz function mentioned earlier. This can be given an approximate solution $\big((0,N_0),(h,y_1),(2h,y_2),\ldots,(nh,y_n)\big)$ where $y_{n+1}=y_n+hg(y_n)$ and $y_0=N_0$. The error of the function at each point could be defined as $\varepsilon=|y_i-x(ih)|$ using the known solution $x(t)$. The figure below shows the approximate solution you'd get for the curve defined by the parameters $a=1,b=2,N_0=0.1$, using points of $h=1.5$.

[image]

Comment: Ok, i kind of understood what you troughly explained. As i stated in my last comment above i suspected that I should plug in $x(t)$ into  $g(x)$. So a new question arises: does the paper mention the exact solution for the ODE? I mean. Wouldn't that be Eq. 2? How can I see the error the numerical method I use is making wrt the exact solution? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX Yes, the equation $x(t)=b\exp\left(-\exp\left(-\left(at+C\right)\right)\right)$ is the true solution so all you'd need to do would be to approximate $a,b$, which can be done with curve-fitting. You could see the error with something like a sum of squared residuals. Are you specifically looking to implement numerical methods to solve differential equations? Because it seems unnecessary here.

Comment: i know it seems unnecessary but I am specifically looking to use several methods (forward/backward Euler, RK45, RK43, Adams-Moulton) and compare results with the one on the paper. There is something I don't get: are you telling me that $x(t) = b exp(-exp(-(at+C)$ is the true solution and it is also the one they say on the paper? So idk if you have experience with NMethds, but wouldn't I be using the exact solution function inside Euler to approximate the solution? Because I should assume I do not have the exact function just the ODE. I am confused.. Thanks in advance

Comment: What I am also trying to figure out is which is the function I should  use as $f(t_i, x_i)$ on  i. e. Euler's method: $x_{i+1}=x_i + hf(t_i, x_i)$?

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX I've addressed this at the end of the answer.

Comment: excelent. I am accepting your answer. One las thing. Could you explicity write $g(x)$ you used? . Thank you

Comment: $g(x)= ax \ln(b/x)$. When you're doing numerical solutions, you want to relate a function of a variable to the differentiated variable, i.e. $g(x)=x'$.

Comment: Depending on what programming environment you are using, I would recommend using any built-in ODE solver as opposed to Euler's method. These solvers (especially those with adaptive step sizes) will solve problems much quicker and more accurately than Euler's method. In python, consider scipy.integrate.ode and in MATLAB consider ode45, for some examples

Comment: That is what I was afraid. I used that exact equation on my method. But I get the results on the first image. I used $a=0.00286$, $b=7.3e10$ and $N_0=1$ (from paper). Also I solve it for $t=[0.1, 700]$. Don't know why my results are so much different :/

Comment: @whpowell96. using my own coded method and both scipy and MATLAB.. Getting same answer on my previous comment :/

Comment: I just solved using ode45 and got a plot that looks exactly like the exact solution you posted. The ode function I gave it was this: 

a = 0.00286;
b = 7.3e10;
myfun = @(t,x)a\*x\*log(b/x);

Comment: Of course, thanks for your input. I totally understood, i was using '@(x,y)' instead of '@(t,x)' on both MATLAB and scipy. Thanks both of  youfor  math and coding help.

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up with an answer, I integrated this equation in MATLAB and got results that look exactly like the exact solution you posted. Code is here:

[image]

[image]

Not sure what further problems you are having but here something that gives the desired results.

Comment: +1.Thank you. This also pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working $$x'=a x \log \left(\frac{b}{x}\right)$$ swith variables and work
$$t'=\frac{1}{a x \log \left(\frac{b}{x}\right)}\implies t+C=-\frac{\log \left(\log \left(\frac{b}{x}\right)\right)}{a}$$ Back to $x$
$$x=b e^{-e^{-a (C+t)}}\implies C=-\frac{\log \left(-\log \left(\frac{N_0}{b}\right)\right)}{a}\implies x=b \left(\frac{N_0}{b}\right)^{e^{-a t}}$$